# How to remove part of of line with sed

Tags: sed

I have a line that I want to remove:

```
"}},"has_video":0}"
```

I have  used this to remove most of what I needed to remove:

```
sed -i 's/&quot;,.*(n)\.(n)//'
```

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?

Comment: Your question is not clear. You need to provide a bigger sample of the file that has the line you want to remove and explain exactly what you expect `sed` to match in order to remove the line. Also, did you actually use `&quot;` in `sed` or did you use it just for rendering purposes?

Comment: I have used that `sed` to remove some spacing and other characters, and now i would like to remove this part in the line `"}},"has_video":0},"` its in the description of a file and the file has alot of these lines

Comment: The end file is xml there i am trying to clean all the unneeded data

Comment: In your question, it is not clear *what* you want to remove from the given string. When I try your command, I get "sed: no input files".

Comment: @vanadium I am trying to remove this `"}},"has_video":0}"` part from the file

Comment: `sed -i 's/"}},"has_video":0}"//' <filename>` should remove just that part of all lines found.

Comment: @Terrance Thanks that helped :) , another question about this kind of matter seems that i missed that there are url links with imgs in the file is there a way to remove them too ? example `1/33/0141483.jpg` the url i know how to remove its just the path of the img i cant get it that much i tried with the combination i have tried some option that i found here but they removing numbers from the areas that are needed these links located in the `<desc> </desc>` section , and i dont want to remove the `<desc> </desc>` data

Comment: If the `.jpg` urls are all the same, you have to escape the `/` with \ so it would be `sed -i 's/1\/33\/0141483.jpg//' filename`

Comment: @Terrance  The path for the `.jpg` is not the same

Comment: I've always had a problem with figuring out all the crazy things you can do in a line with sed, awk, etc.  But, if all the URLs for the jpgs are in the same format of `#/##/#######.jpg` I guess you could do something like this and I know, it very ugly, but it might work `sed -i 's/[0-9]\/[0-9][0-9]\/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].jpg//' filename`  I know there are those here that really understand how to make that work efficiently.  Maybe ask a new question on that one.

Comment: @Terrance Thank you very much you helped me alot :)

Comment: @Terrance Is it possible to get your email i have few question that i would like to discuss in private if its possible